# Event isn't getting removed

Tags: javascript

I have a `myDiv.mousedown`, `window.mousemove`, and `window.mouseup` event. I'm trying to organize my code, and have it clean. So I created a `function` and returned the 3 event handlers.
The `mousedown` event adds a `mousemove` event, and the `mouseup` event removes the `mousemove` event.

The problem is, the `mousemove` event never gets removed. The `mouseup` event does get fired, but the `mousemove` event stays. What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it (in a clean and organized way)?

#### JSFiddle

```js
var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');

var VeryUsefullClass = (function() {

  function VeryUsefullClass(parentElem, options) {
    var _this = this;
    _this.index = 0;
    _this.mouseHandlerBinded = mouseHandler.bind(_this);

    myDiv.addEventListener('mousedown', _this.mouseHandlerBinded().mouseDown);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', _this.mouseHandlerBinded().mouseUp);
  }

  function mouseHandler() {
    var _this = this;
    var obj = {
      mouseDown: function(e) {
        console.log('mouseDown');
        window.addEventListener('mousemove', _this.mouseHandlerBinded().mouseMove);
      },
      mouseMove: function(e) {
        myDiv.innerHTML = 'mouseMove ' + _this.index++;
      },
      mouseUp: function(e) {
        console.log('mouseUp');
        _this.index = 0;
        window.removeEventListener('mousemove', _this.mouseHandlerBinded().mouseMove);
      }
    }
    return obj;
  }

  return VeryUsefullClass;
})();

console.clear();

var hello = new VeryUsefullClass();
```

```css
#myDiv {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: You must remove event with binded function it self .

Comment: @passion `_this.mouseHandlerBinded()` is a binded function....?

Answer (score 0):

`_this.mouseHandlerBinded().mouseMove` , you will get the function which is a new function , never binded .

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');

var VeryUsefullClass = (function() {
     var mdown= mouseHandler().mouseDown;
     var mup = mouseHandler().mouseUp;  
     var mmove; // unbind with this function will work

    function VeryUsefullClass(parentElem, options) {
        var _this = this;
        _this.index = 0;

        mmove = mouseHandler.call(_this).mouseMove;

        myDiv.addEventListener('mousedown', mdown);
        window.addEventListener('mouseup', mup);
    }
    function mouseHandler() {
        var _this = this;
        var obj = {
            mouseDown: function(e) {
                console.log('mouseDown');

                window.addEventListener('mousemove', mmove);
            },
            mouseMove: function(e) {
                myDiv.innerHTML = 'mouseMove ' + (_this.index++);
            },
            mouseUp: function(e) {
                console.log('mouseUp');
                _this.index = 0;
                window.removeEventListener('mousemove', mmove);
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }
    return VeryUsefullClass;
})();

console.clear();

var hello = new VeryUsefullClass();
```

Comment: Is that organized? I feel like there's a lot of unneeded variables?

Comment: Also, the mousemove event never gets fired?

Comment: @Jessica  What you need is not something like `drag` ? then why `remove` event when `mouseUp` ?

Comment: The first time you click it, it says NAN

Comment: @Jessica  yes, because `this` in handler function is `window`  , which has no variable called `index`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123997/discussion-between-passion-and-jessica).